# Remove x axis and y axis black lines with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am trying to remove the black lines from x axis and y axis and leave the labels (letters & numbers) but without success. I've done it for right and top side with the following code:

```
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
```

If I try for instance to use:

```
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

it removes the labels but the black lines continue there. Any tip how could achieve this? I am trying to change a few graphs done with matplotlib to a more "clean" version. Thanks.

My graphs are like this one below:

[image]

Comment: In addition to the answers below, if you wanted to remove the ticks as well you could use `ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)`

Comment: Very useful . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make all spines invisible:

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
```

Plus, as suggested by David:

```
ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the colour of the edge to white like this

```
for edge_i in ['top', 'bottom', 'right', 'left']:
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_edgecolor("white")
```

I hope that helps